# Github doesn't change the database in our teams django environment

Tags: sql, django, database, github

Our team is using a django environment to develop a website, the main issue is one team member recently updated one of the databases and the change will not care through mysql. We are literally on the same branch but the database tables are completely different. We are using the current version of django, python, and mysql are the development environment and github to share work.

Comment: So I'm clear, a teammate updated a class, but when you run the migrations your database tables don't end up the same?
Have you double-checked that you're all running the same versions of everything?

Comment: yes we are using the same version of everything

Comment: Interesting. I would start troubleshooting by making certain _all_ the migrations were run on the dbs. Also, please describe how you mean "completely different"? Is the updated db the correct one? or is the non-updated db correct?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is `Git` is never synced with your `MySQL` database. MySQL Database is a local property of your system. If you use `SQLite` then that can be synced by Git. If you both need to access the same database you need some database in the cloud so that you both are on the same page.

Also, you need to migrate the migrations to get those same tables this is independent of the system but is dependent on the number of migrations created and applied.

This will create same tables and columns. Just run this the terminal

```sh
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```